# Ignore #N/A when using Unique formula

Tags: excel-formula

I am using the formula below to return unique roles from a table column. This works fine until toward the bottom when i get #N/A's. I have tried both `=IFNA` & `=IFERROR` but still get them.

```
{=IFNA(UNIQUE(HrsRoleEchoPay[E-Source Role]),"")}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to `FILTER()` your result, e.g.

```
=LET(u,UNIQUE(HrsRoleEchoPay[E-Source Role],FILTER(u,ISTEXT(u)))
```

Comment: Hi, in the end used `=UNIQUE(FILTER(HrsRoleEchoPay[E-Source Role],HrsRoleEchoPay[E-Source Role]<>""))'`